# How do I obtain a wordlist without profanity, special characters or offensive words?

Tags: passwords

I want to send out english words to my users to use as a two-factor authentication code for my application. For usability I would like to exclude words that include any special characters such as ï, å, ä etc and at the same time I would like to avoid having users typing in words such as "jihad" or "vagina" that could be seen as weird or offensive. Randomly generated strings is not an option in this case, even though I am aware of the security benefits of such a solution.

I haven't been able to find any curated wordlist that match these criteria, and I can't manually go through 20 000 or more words to detect offensive words. I started considering using something like a list of cities but even there I will run into usability problems quite quickly. How should I best go about this?

Comment: If you consider religious concepts and anatomical names to be offensive, you're gonna have quite a lot of work pruning a word list.  If you are presenting two words together, it's even harder, as many seemingly innocent words are rude when paired...  I don't think I need to give any examples.  I think this is why many auth codes contain random characters and/or numeric sequences.

Comment: @paddy It sounds like my best bet would be coming up with a collection of something that exists in great numbers and still matches the limitations listed above...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading a children's book in pure text and running

`cat childrens_book.txt | grep -o -w '\w\{5,9\}[a-z]' > words.txt` to grep words between 5 to 9 letters long.

Then I just made each word unique, and it resulted in a 18 000 word long list that I can be fairly sure doesn't contain offensive language.

Comment: Good solution for single words...  But remember that you are presenting two words.  So, while the words 'tasty' and 'beaver' are innocuous on their own, the two together might offend (or amuse) your users.  There are countless examples of such word pairings, and you can't hope to rule them all out, even if you indexed the entire [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com) -- I checked, and my example is not an entry.  Hence why many services tend to only offer one english word, while the other is an alphanumeric jumble or a word that looks english-like but is not.

Comment: Can I ask where you got the childrens_book.txt from?  I'm facing the same issue and am desperate for a safe word list.  Mine is for a hangman game, but I'm hitting a wall everywhere I go.

Comment: @robster I used Alice in Wonderland found on the Open Book Project